# JobOperator.restart with failed batch execution id is not resuming the JOB (instead marking the job as COMPLETED with a new Job instance)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

Java:17
Spring Boot: 3.0.5
Spring Batch 5.0

Problem statement:
Main batch process fails (intentionally for the sake of testing restart)
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION (STATUS and EXIT_CODE both the column values are marked as FAILED)
Used -> JobLauncher.run (Jobname, Jobparams) to launch the Job.

Note:

- Job is not declared as a "bean"
- Auto Incrementor is not used:

`Job testBatchResumeJob = new JobBuilder("TEST_BATCH_RESUME_JOB", jobRepository).start(step).build();`

Using the previous step "Failed" Job Execution id, while trying to restart the Job using
jobOperator.restart(failedBatchExecutionId) below are the observations:

1. New JOB instance with new Step entry is created and the status of the JOB and STEP is marked "COMPLETED" (In BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION and BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION tables)
2. Reader, Writer and Processor beans are not getting executed at all

Following approaches tried out but not working

- Removal of “Auto Incrementor” from the main batch process.
- Post Processor Bean approach (both in common config for all jobs and at specific job level)

  @Bean
  public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(@Qualifier("myBatchJobRegistry") JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
  JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
  postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
  return postProcessor;
  }
- Explicit job registration and removal of Post processor bean

  ```
  if (!jobRegistry.getJobNames().contains(testBatchResumeJob .getName())) {
   jobRegistry.register(new ReferenceJobFactory(testBatchResumeJob ));
  }
  ```
- Changed the Job as a “Bean” and related infra changes .

Sample Minimal Code:

My Batch Common Custom Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyBatchConfig {
  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "myBatchDataSource")
  public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    DataSource myBatchDbSrc = DataSourceBuilder.create().username(getUsername()).password(getPassword()).url(getUrl()).build();
    if (myBatchDbSrc != null && myBatchDbSrc instanceof HikariDataSource) {
      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
      HikariDataSource hikariDatsource = (HikariDataSource) myBatchDbSrc;
      hikariDatsource.setSchema(getSchema());
    }
    return myBatchDbSrc;
  }

  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(@Qualifier("myBatchDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
  }

  @Bean(name = "myBatchJobRepository")
  public JobRepository jobRepository(@Qualifier("myBatchDataSource") DataSource batchDataSource,
      @Qualifier("transactionManager") JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager) throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(batchTransactionManager);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
  }

  @Bean(name = "myBatchJobLauncher")
  public JobLauncher jobLauncher(@Qualifier("myBatchJobRepository") JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
    TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
  }

  @Bean (name = "myBatchJobExplorer")
  public JobExplorer jobExplorer(@Qualifier("myBatchDataSource") DataSource dataSource,@Qualifier("transactionManager")JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager) throws Exception {
      final JobExplorerFactoryBean bean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
      bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
      bean.setTransactionManager(batchTransactionManager);
      bean.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
      bean.setJdbcOperations(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
      bean.afterPropertiesSet();
      return bean.getObject();
  }
  
  @Bean (name ="myBatchJobRegistry")
  public JobRegistry jobRegistry() throws Exception {
    return new MapJobRegistry();
  }

 @Bean (name = "myBatchJobOperator")
  public JobOperator jobOperator(@Qualifier("myBatchJobLauncher") JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Qualifier("myBatchJobRepository") JobRepository jobRepository,
          @Qualifier("myBatchJobRegistry") JobRegistry jobRegistry, @Qualifier("myBatchJobExplorer") JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
      final SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
      jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
      jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
      jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
      jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
      return jobOperator;
  }
}
```

My Batch Resume Job:

```
@Component("TESTRESUMEBATCHJOB")
@Configuration
public class TestMyBatchResumeConfig implements IBatchJobFactory{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("transactionManager")
    private JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager;
    
    /** The job repository. */
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myBatchJobRepository")
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myBatchJobRegistry")
    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;
    
    @Override
    

public Job getBatchJob() throws Exception{
            ItemProcessor<TestBatchModel, TestBatchModel> itemProcessor = appContext
                .getBean(TestBatchProcessor.class);
            ItemWriter<TestBatchModel> itemWriter = appContext.getBean(TestBatchWriter.class);
            TestBatchReader reader = appContext.getBean(TestBatchReader.class);
            Step step = new StepBuilder("TEST_BATCH_RESUME_STEP", jobRepository)
            .<TestBatchModel, TestBatchModel>chunk(5, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader.getPagingItemReader()).processor(itemProcessor).writer(itemWriter)
            .taskExecutor(testBatchTaskExecutor())
            .throttleLimit(2).build();
        
        Job testBatchResumeJob  = new JobBuilder("TEST_BATCH_RESUME_JOB", jobRepository).start(step).build();
        return testBatchResumeJob ;   
    }
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor testBatchTaskExecutor() {
            SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor acctStmtTaskExecuter = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
            acctStmtTaskExecuter.setConcurrencyLimit(100);
            acctStmtTaskExecuter.setThreadPriority(1);
            acctStmtTaskExecuter.setThreadNamePrefix("TEST_BATCH_RESUME");
        return acctStmtTaskExecuter;
      }
}
```

ItemReader:

```
@Component
public class SubhayuTestBatchModelReader {
    
      @Autowired
      @Qualifier("myBatchDataSource")
      private DataSource myBatchDataSource;
      
     /** The Constant SELECT_CLAUSE_PARTY. */
      private static final String SELECT_CLAUSE_PARTY = "SELECT SOURCE_REFERENCE_ID, PARTY_ID, PARTY_NAME";

      /** The Constant FROM_CLAUSE_PARTY. */
      private static final String FROM_CLAUSE_PARTY = "FROM MY_PARTY ";

      /** The Constant WHERE_CLAUSE_PARTY. */
      private static final String WHERE_CLAUSE_PARTY = "CONSOLIDATE_STATEMENT_FLAG='Y'";
      
      public JdbcPagingItemReader<SubhayuTestBatchModel> getPagingItemReader() throws Exception {
            
            JdbcPagingItemReader<SubhayuTestBatchModel> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
            reader.setDataSource(myBatchDataSource);
            reader.setFetchSize(5);
            reader.setPageSize(5);
            reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(SubhayuTestBatchModel.class));
            Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
            sortKeys.put("PARTY_ID", Order.ASCENDING);

            SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean factory = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(myBatchDataSource);
            factory.setSelectClause(SELECT_CLAUSE_PARTY);
            factory.setFromClause(FROM_CLAUSE_PARTY);
            factory.setWhereClause(WHERE_CLAUSE_PARTY);

            factory.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
            reader.setQueryProvider(factory.getObject());
            reader.afterPropertiesSet();
            return reader;
        }
}
```

ItemWriter:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class TestBatchModelWriter implements ItemWriter<TestBatchModel> {

    /** The Constant GREP_KEY. */
    private static final String GREP_KEY = "TEST_RESUME_BATCH_PROCESS|";
      
    @Override
    public void write(Chunk<? extends TestBatchModel> arg0) throws Exception {
        for(TestBatchModel testModelItem : arg0 ) {
            LOGGER.info(GREP_KEY + "Inside Writer, Writing Item for Party ID: "+ testModelItem.getParty_id());
            if(testModelItem.getParty_id().equals("TEST0027")) {
                throw new NullPointerException("For Party ID: "+ testModelItem.getParty_id());
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

ItemProcessor:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class TestBatchModelProcessor implements ItemProcessor<TestBatchModel, TestBatchModel>  {

    
    /** The Constant GREP_KEY. */
    private static final String GREP_KEY = "TEST_RESUME_BATCH_PROCESS|";
    @Override
    public TestBatchModel process(TestBatchModel arg0) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info(GREP_KEY+ "Inside Processor for line item: "+ arg0.getParty_id() );
        return arg0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> New JOB instance with new Step entry is created

That means you are not restarting the same job instance. Make sure to pass the same identifying job parameters (the incrementer is probably still used even if you think it is not).

Comment: Can you please clarify how to check/validate "the incrementor is probably still used even if you think it is not"! Here is my API sample request to resume the batch job which failed before:                                                                                                                                       {
    "appId": "TEST",
    "appJobBeanName": "TESTBATCHRESUMEJOB",
    "appRestartJobExecutionId" : "181",
    "appJobParamsMap": {
        "test": "false"
    }
}

Comment: Sure! If you share a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, I can clarify that point.

Comment: Thank you. Please refer to "Sample Minimal Code" section in the main post, Awaiting for your valuable response with the solution.

Comment: The job definition you shared does not use an incrementer, so jobOperator.restart(failedBatchExecutionId) should restart the failed execution and not create another instance. I can't see the cause from what you shared.

Comment: I have highlighted in the main post : Job is not declared as a "bean" and  Auto Incrementor is not used. Shared the sample "Reader, Writer, Processor" for your use. Please check what else could be required to make resume/restart work as expected.

Comment: Any further updates! The reported issue should be reproducible easily with the code shared. Please help.

Comment: No, unfortunately. As I said previously, I can't see the cause of that from what you shared. I am trying to help, but without reproducing the issue, I can't. Create a github repo or a zip and include the detailed instructions on how to reproduce the issue and I can look deeper.

Comment: The reported issue was due to ItemReader(example given above) in multithreaded environment was reading all data successfully (available in database) and in the given writer (example given above) when exception was thrown, the main batch process was marked as FAILED having no items left for reader (for resume). Hence in the resume/retry was not having any job/item left. Still problem is "the chunk which failed is ignored during the resume/retry, but other unprocessed chuck is getting processed. Kindly have a look at the given reader and suggest what is needed to continue from the failed chuck